# Join semilattice examples amongst semigroup instances in Haskell

Tags: haskell, semigroup

I am collecting examples of join semilattices amongst `Semigroup` instances. As you may know join semilattice is similar to semigroup but requires additionally commutativity and idempotence. From the quick scan of the libraries on hackage I found the following examples:

- `Data.Semigroup.Max`
- `Data.Semigroup.All`
- `Data.Semigroup.Any`
- `Data.Map.Append.AppendMap`

I'm curious whether you came across any other (interesting and useful) join semilattices examples in Haskell libraries?

Comment: "Big list" questions are typically considered off-topic here, because it's almost impossible to write an answer that is both complete and future-proof. I know that's not your goal, but... it *is* part of the site's stated goals, and the way it maintains the property that answers live forever is by banning questions that can't be answered in such a way. There may be other fora that welcome this question in the spirit it was intended; I encourage you to seek them out.

Answer (score 1):

Ordered strictly increasing lists of wholly compared elements (where equality implies sameness) seem to form join semilattice under [`Data.List.Ordered.union`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.7.0/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html#v:union) from `data-ordlist` package.

Answer (score 0):

[`Data.IntSet.IntSet`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-IntSet.html#t:IntSet) has the set union operation as its `<>`, which seems to meet your criteria. This may be true for other sets too, as long as you're okay with pathological `Eq` instances for their elements breaking it.

This is also true for `Proxy`, but that's about as far from useful as you can get.